# Set a fixed HTML page height size

Tags: html, css, page-size

I want to set the size of a table so that I can use in line scrolling. So the table height needs to be the remaining height of the page but never get any larger. And I don't want a hard fix like pixel size. I want it to vary based on the window size. Anyone know the css for this?

Comment: If one of the answers below worked for you, please flag it as such. If not, post your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `vh` unit, but you will need to specify a height for the layout elements on your page if you want the table height to be the "remaining height of the page".

What is a `vh`? `1vh` is 1% of the viewport height, the height inside the window when the page is loaded. `100vh` is 100% of the viewport height. I don't believe the height is adjusted when the window is resized.

```html
<style type="text/css">
div#header {
  height: 25vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}
div#table {
  height: 75vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}
</style>
<body>
  <div id="header">This text explains the contents of the table below.</div>
  <div id="table"><table>...</table></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could either be accomplished using Javascript, or you could try the following code:

```
.myTable {
    position:fixed;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

You aren't able to use the `height: 100%;` directive, however. It doesn't work when trying to use it on a child nested in a `<html>` or `<body>` directly.

**Edit:** As far as I am aware, the `height: 100%` directive doesn't work on any element nested in an element without a fixed height. I mean, `height: 100%` will only work if its parent explicitly is told how tall to be (eg, `height: 600px;`).